# same lambda for many threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, lambda

I have a code following the following structure:

```
//some const variables here


std::function<void(int threadID, NumericMatrix * mat)> threadT = [const1,const2](int threadID, NumericMatrix * mat) {
//a lot of variables defined inside lamdas

}

NumericMatrix * mat1 = new NumericMatrix(N, nEstimators);
std::thread t1( threadT, 1, mat1 );
NumericMatrix * mat2 = new NumericMatrix(N, nEstimators);
std::thread t2( threadT, 2, mat2 );
t1.join();
t2.join();

return;
```

When ever I try to run it I receive a lot segmentation fault errors, but when I try to run only one thread there is no problem. I don't think there's a problem of mutex, both threads are only accessing variables defined in

So I wonder: is it because I'm reusing the same lambdas for each thread? If so, how could I work around this? By making a copy of threadT (how)?

Obs.: I couldn't find a way to debug this with gdb because it's compiled inside R.

Comment: how are you compiling it?

Comment: Do you compile with -pthread? Your lambda is automatically copied by the thread constructor. Also I would use auto for the lambda type, that just looks cleaner.

Comment: I'm compiling inside R with inline package, but I'd added -pthread to cxx_flags (where I added -std=c++11) and the problem persists. It's seens that the problem is related to Rcpp instead of C++.

Comment: after some time working on it I realized that it was a problem with some functions of Rcpp package, thank you for your help telling me it wasn't a problem with lambda after all. And I'll also start using auto from now =]